# clojure.set/difference fails when result would is empty and right set has higher cardinality

Tags: clojure, set, set-theory

I try to eleminate elements from a set, that are present on a different sequence in Clojure. But the `clojure.set/difference` doesn't seem to work as I expect it. Where is my error?

Some examples:

### Removing empty sequence

```
(difference #{3 2} '())
```

Result: `#{3 2}` (as expected)

### Removing some of the elements

```
(difference #{3 2} '(3))
```

Result: `#{2}` (as expected)

### Removing elements not present in the set

```
(difference #{3 2} '(1))
```

Result: `#{3 2}` (as expected)

### Removing all elements

```
(difference #{3 2} '(2 3))
```

Result: `#{}` (as expected)

### Removing more elements that present

```
(difference #{3 2} '(1 2 3))
```

Instead of a result I get **IllegalArgumentException contains? not supported on type: clojure.lang.PersistentList  clojure.lang.RT.contains (RT.java:814)**

Expected result: `#{}`

So it seems, that the `clojure.set/difference` function fails, when the result is the empty set and the set of elements to be removed has a higher cardinality than the original set. But the question is: why doesn't this work? I'd expect that this is a legal application of `clojure.set/difference`.

Comment: Related failure case: `(clojure.set/difference #{1 2} [3 4 5])` evaluates to `#{}`. In both cases wrapping the non-set with the `set` function to turn into sets makes it work proper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because the [difference](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/set.clj#L48) function compares the sizes of the two inputs and iterates over the smaller collection and removes elements from the first one. If the second argument is larger, it uses `contains?` to see if an item in the first collection exists in the second. `contains?` is not supported on lists so you get the exception.

The functions in `clojure.set` should only be called with set arguments.

Comment: This answer is correct; this works as expected: `(difference #{3 2} #{1 2 3})`

Comment: In `(difference s1 s2)` the elements are always being removed from `s1`, no matter the relative cardinality The differences is between testing all elements in `s1` and removing each one if it is in `s2` or taking each element of `s2` by turn and removing it from `s1`, if there.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That solves my problem. Actually the real second argument in my code is not a literal but the result of another function. But I can convert this to a set using the set operator.